# Completely new to SQL, need help group by with rollup

Tags: mysql

I'm learning MYSQL using workbench (no programming experience) and I've successfully managed to create a procedure to total sales and group by month with rollup.  However, my total in the sales is named December and I've 2 December months.  Why is this?  I've searched for an answer but can't seem to find one.  Here's my code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MonthlySales()
    BEGIN
        SELECT monthname(Date) AS MonthlySales, SUM(OrderValue) AS TotalSales
        FROM customerorders
        GROUP BY Month(Date) with rollup;
    END //
```

My output is:

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl7tv.png)

Comment: Where is the output in that image coming from? Perhaps it is the post-processing of the result that is having an issue; MySQL should yield NULL for the grouping fields in the rollup results.

Comment: When I run the code from SELECT to ROLLUP; I get that output in MYSQL workbench.  I don't understand why it's duplicating.  Is there a way I can set to null within the code?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Do you get the same output from running the query bare as you do from executing the stored procedure?

Comment: I get the same output when I execute the procedure.  I tried the code on another table and I got null for the total but for this table it seems to not work.  Could be a bug.

Comment: Output with no input again. How dull.

Comment: Are the dates for a period bigger than 12 Month? so that it also shows last year data

Comment: No the dates are from January to December, all within the same year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra December label is due to the function in the group by clause. Just use the name of the output column.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MonthlySales()
    BEGIN
        SELECT monthname(Date) AS MonthlySales, SUM(OrderValue) AS TotalSales
        FROM customerorders
        GROUP BY MonthlySales with rollup;
    END //
```

Test Input:

`'2019-01-01 00:00:00','93.00'
'2019-07-16 00:00:00','2.00'
'2020-05-13 00:00:00','14.00'
'2020-08-17 00:00:00','80.00'
'2021-07-27 00:00:00','1.00'
'2022-04-01 00:00:00','38.00'
'2022-05-28 00:00:00','28.00'
'2022-09-11 00:00:00','41.00'
'2023-01-18 00:00:00','70.00'
'2023-09-09 00:00:00','21.00'
'2024-08-06 00:00:00','76.00'
'2025-07-23 00:00:00','18.00'
'2026-01-23 00:00:00','9.00'
'2026-07-20 00:00:00','52.00'
'2026-08-11 00:00:00','100.00'
'2026-12-02 00:00:00','48.00'
'2027-09-22 00:00:00','74.00'
'2028-07-31 00:00:00','26.00'
'2029-01-30 00:00:00','28.00'
'2029-04-26 00:00:00','33.00'
'2029-06-09 00:00:00','93.00'
'2030-06-04 00:00:00','92.00'
'2031-03-12 00:00:00','87.00'
'2031-12-20 00:00:00','62.00'
'2032-12-16 00:00:00','32.00'
'2033-04-10 00:00:00','18.00'
'2033-08-09 00:00:00','97.00'
'2034-06-01 00:00:00','62.00'
'2034-06-30 00:00:00','33.00'
'2034-07-04 00:00:00','88.00'
'2034-12-19 00:00:00','64.00'
'2035-01-09 00:00:00','40.00'
'2035-03-13 00:00:00','58.00'
'2035-09-16 00:00:00','24.00'
'2036-01-23 00:00:00','6.00'
'2036-07-03 00:00:00','49.00'
'2036-08-25 00:00:00','71.00'
'2037-05-05 00:00:00','92.00'
'2038-04-17 00:00:00','32.00'
'2038-11-28 00:00:00','85.00'
'2039-11-04 00:00:00','63.00'
'2039-11-24 00:00:00','33.00'
'2040-09-01 00:00:00','6.00'
'2040-12-13 00:00:00','87.00'
'2041-07-10 00:00:00','17.00'
'2041-11-11 00:00:00','98.00'`

Result from original query:

`'January', '246.00'
'March', '145.00'
'April', '121.00'
'May', '134.00'
'June', '280.00'
'July', '253.00'
'August', '424.00'
'September', '166.00'
'November', '279.00'
'December', '293.00'
'December', '2341.00'`

Result from query using column name:

`'April', '121.00'
'August', '424.00'
'December', '293.00'
'January', '246.00'
'July', '253.00'
'June', '280.00'
'March', '145.00'
'May', '134.00'
'November', '279.00'
'September', '166.00'
NULL, '2341.00'`

Comment: Thank you this works.  So naming MonthlySales gave the Null instead of Month(Date).  I'll note this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a bug in your environment's/code's handling of such results, you could try wrapping your query to "push" the value to something recognizable (also applicable if you just want to "name" your rollup results).

Given:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(myDate) AS theMonth, SUM(someValue) AS total
FROM aTable 
GROUP BY theMonth WITH ROLLUP
;
```

Change to:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN theMonth IS NULL THEN 'Year' ELSE theMonth END AS theMonth
   , total
FROM (
   theQueryAbove
) AS q
;
```

Note: I could have used `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` instead of the `CASE` statement, but the `CASE` version lends itself to extension for multi-field grouping...

```
CASE WHEN theMonth IS NULL AND theYear IS NOT NULL THEN 'Year'
WHEN theMonth IS NULL AND theYear IS NULL THEN 'Overall'
ELSE theMonth
END
```

Edit: And if you **don't** want that much info, and want to keep things succinct, you can just do `COALESCE(theYear, '') AS theYear, COALESCE(theMonth, '') AS theMonth`

---

More explicitly, this is what your specific query should look like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MonthlySales IS NULL THEN 'Year' ELSE MonthlySales END AS MonthlySales
   , TotalSales
FROM (
    SELECT MONTHNAME(Date) AS MonthlySales, SUM(OrderValue) AS TotalSales
    FROM customerorders
    GROUP BY MonthlySales WITH ROLLUP
) AS q
;
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I haven't used CASE and COALESCE before so forgive me if this question is simple but is this correct in how I put the code in?

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN theMonth IS NULL THEN 'Year' ELSE theMonth END AS theMonth
   , total FROM (
   theQueryAbove
) AS q;
SELECT monthname(Date) AS MonthlySales, SUM(OrderValue) AS TotalSales
FROM customerorders
GROUP BY Month(Date) WITH ROLLUP;

Comment: Or do I delete SELECT and use SELECT CASE WHEN, add in the rest of my other columns FROM theQueryAbove and table name?

Comment: Thanks, I've tried numerous ways and the code doesn't seem to be working for me.  I think I'll just delete the entire database again and see does it fix the issue.

Comment: @cmdublin See the edit I added to the bottom for a more specific solution.

Comment: Great thank you for this, it also works.  I'll save the code for future use.  Thank you for your time.